# A large array of needles in a haystack. Better Approach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am wondering if there is a better approach to a problem I have.  I have a mongodb, node/javascript implementation and one small piece of it requires me to find if a user entered "sentence" contains a "phrase" that matches a large list of possible phrases (over 300k) stored in Mongodb.  Each phrase is no more that 2 or 3 words.  The user entered sentences may be larger, maybe 7 or 8 words.

The only solution I have come up with is to query the database and put all of the phrases into a very large array and then loop through the array (with ._map) to see if any exist within the sentence.

But creating such a large array doesn't make sense, and performance is crucial.  And I looked into mongodb $text and $search features, but I don't see how they can be used, since I am searching for the presence of many phrases (in the database) to one sentence (user supplied as a parameter in node).

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's usable in your context, but have you looked into / considered using a trie-based solution? Here's the one I use for an autocomplete-related module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/triecomplete

Comment: That looks interesting - but it would still require me to put all of the 300k needs into an array.  And having such a large array seems bad.  Or maybe I should ask the question: "how do you tell when an array is too large."

Comment: I think that is indeed a better question. The linked solution performs well even on arrays of over 500,000 words, which seems to be more than enough for your problem.

Comment: Does order matter? You're basically looking for 2-grams and 3-grams? Can you not form all 2 and 3-grams from the sentence and search for each in the db if the number of possibilities is small?